# Is there any Netbeans plugin that replaces Eclipse Sapphire? (Data Binding to GUI)

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, user-interface, binding

I use **[Eclipse Sapphire](http://www.eclipse.org/sapphire/)** to create editors for specific XML files. I have multiple editors for multiple XML files, in a single application using RCP.

What I need is to migrate from `Eclipse RCP` to `Netbeans Platform`. The only problem I have is to find a competitive alternative to `Sapphire` in Netbeans.

After searching I found **[Binding Beans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-binding.html)** but I'm not sure it can totally replace it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> Sapphire aims to raise UI writing to a higher level of abstraction.
>   The core premise is that the basic building block of UI should not be
>   a widget (text box, label, button, etc.), but rather a property
>   editor.

A bit at a lower level, but note that the JavaBeans specification also has support for PropertyEditors:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyEditor.html

Have a look at the java.beans package to see what's provided by the JDK:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/package-summary.html

Comment: So if I have an Enum property and a Boolean property, how can I get the GUI to render the first one as a ComboBox and the other as a Checkbox ? Is `Binding Beans` capable of recognizing such a thing?

Comment: Have a look at the static methods of PropertyEditorManager: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyEditorManager.html